# if_else true value defaulting to NA

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I'm trying to mutate a new column in my data_frame using dplyr's if_else statement. However, the value I've assigned to the vector if TRUE is defaulting to NA, while the FALSE value appears to be working. I'm not sure if it's related to the variable type or what, but I'd really appreciate some help with this.

**My data**

```
data <- 
 data.frame(SP = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
            Sale = c("Y","Y",NA,"Y",NA),
            WWS = c(NA,NA,"Y",NA,"Y"))
```

**Existing code to add new column**

```
data %>%
  mutate(RMV = if_else(
               Sale == "Y" & WWS != "Y", "Keep","-"))
```

When I run the above code, all the TRUE values default to NA, not Keep.

Comment: We can't compare NA values, try: `NA == 1`, `NA == NA`, etc.

Comment: `data %>%
      mutate(RMV = dplyr::if_else( ( !is.na( Sale ) & Sale == "Y" ) & ( WWS != "Y" | is.na( WWS ) )  , "Keep", "-" ) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you want something like this:

```
data %>%
  mutate(RMV = (Sale == "Y" & !is.na(Sale)) & (WWS != "Y" | is.na(WWS)))

  SP Sale  WWS   RMV
1  A    Y <NA>  TRUE
2  B    Y <NA>  TRUE
3  C <NA>    Y FALSE
4  D    Y <NA>  TRUE
5  E <NA>    Y FALSE
```

Problem with your original attempt is explained in the help for `?Comparison`:

> Missing values (NA) and NaN values are regarded as non-comparable even to themselves, so comparisons involving them will always result in NA.

Meaning basically you can't compare an NA using any of the comparison operators.  So using any of the following:

```
x < y
x > y
x <= y
x >= y
x == y
x != y
```

...where either (or both!) x or y above is NA it will always result in NA.

Comment: you can use `is.na()` to check for NA's...

Comment: @Wimpel Absolutely correct, thank you!  I've edited now per your comment to cover more cases.  I.e., the OP's data sample doesn't have a case where Sales is NA and WWS !='Y'.  However, best practice dictates we should handle that case by also testing for !is.na(Sales) as Wimpel very kindly suggests.